# Codename one:Copy msg to clipboard

Tags: codenameone, mobile-application

I have developed application using codename one.I have to copy message to clipboard from application.
So is there any default functionality in codename one for that? if not then is there any other solution in codename one ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Display` class has a copy to clipboard API call but it isn't implemented on iOS currently. You have two options:

Use the share intent which is often what you "really" want when offering copy to clipboard.

Place the data in a text area or text field and open editing using start edit. This will allow the user to use native copy & paste functionality of the device.

Comment: Its working fine on android .but not on IOS.What is the solution for IOS?

Comment: You can use the share API but currently we don't support programmatic copy/paste in Codename One on iOS mostly because we never got around to doing it.